# import `prom` from `prom-client` module missing but it's installed. How can I `import prom-client` accordingly?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, import, node-modules

I'm refactoring two old Javascript services into Typescript. I have updated all of the NPM dependencies accordingly and those that are deprecated have been replaced by other packages or have been removed entirely. Now I'm running into the following;

When I install the package `prom-client` and use `import prom from 'prom-client'` the module is not found. The package contains a `index.d.ts` typings file. If I manually add a folder `prom-client` within `node_modules/@types` the module is found with the *import* statement.

- I know that I can use ***require()***, but I use *import* syntax
  everywhere so I rather not use *require()*.
- There is no *@types/prom-client* package which is there for example
        *@types/express*.
- Using NodeJS 12.16.1 and `es2020`.
- Syntax like `import * as prom from 'prom-client'` do not work.
- I tried reinstalling all the packages a few times without result.
- On code-sandbox the `import prom from 'prom-client'` statement
  **does** work. But I can't see the difference.

[image: Edit muddy-butterfly-codej]

How can I `import prom-client` accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation this will be enough

```
import { register } from "prom-client";
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
//create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.write("Hello World!"); //write a response to the client
    res.end(); //end the response
  })
  .listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080

const app = express();

app.get("/prom-test", function(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
  res.send(register.metrics());
});
```

Comment: Your solution works. I didn't think about importing `constants` and `classes`  from the package. However it still raises another question. Why I cannot import `prom-client` as a whole? Like the example? Why doen't is take the typings file from *node_modules/prom-client/index.d.ts*? Am I missing a configuration here? Can you elaborate on this? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: it possible as well. Try `import * as prom from "prom-client";prom.collectDefaultMetrics();`, On my env all fine- without any problem.

Comment: I figured out that I had a dumb mistake in my `tsconfig.ts` file. That why some imports did not work. Not only *prom-client* didn't work. The configuration error was `"module": "es2020"`  which can be set to 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. When switch back to commonjs every import worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {prom} from "prom-client"
```

I faced the same problem. This one worked for me